# python string spanning multiple lines indentation

Tags: python, string, format, styles

I am creating string that includes carriage returns and is too long to be on a single line (from a style perspective).  In order to not have white-space at the beginning of each line, I have to remove the indent.  This functions fine but it looks horrible since the code is no longer indented under the function.  Is there any way to do this, maintain the indent, and not have the whitespace?

```
# report final results
        report_profit = f'\n\
        Financial Analysis \n\
-------------------------------------------\n\
   Total Months:  {self.month_count}\n\
   Total Profit:  ${"{:,.0f}".format(self.profit)}\n\
 Average Change:  ${"{:,.2f}".format(self.average_diff)}\n\
Positive Change:  {self.greatest_dif}\n\
Negative Change:  {self.worst_dif}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your string encasing it with triple quotes, which will store the newlines, tabs etc and print the statement out with the formatting you create it with.

```
report = f'''
       Finacial analysis
--------------------------------
   Total Months: Test
   Total Profit: Test
 Average Change: Test
Positive Change: Test
Negative Change: Test'''

print(report)
```

Comment: This is a nice feature an I will use it.  It looks nicer.  However, I am trying to keep the code indented with where we are in the code.

Comment: If I place this inside a function that is inside a class it will print with 10 lines of indentation.  The other option is to ignore the indentation and place the second line without indentation.  This will print without indentation but then perfectly indented code looks sloppy.

If that adds clarity to what I am asking

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work like this:

```
...
    ....
        report_profit = f'\n' +\
            'Financial Analysis \n' +\
            '-------------------------------------------\n' +\
            f'Total Months:  {self.month_count}\n' +\
            f'Total Profit:  ${"{:,.0f}".format(self.profit)}\n' +\
            f'Average Change:  ${"{:,.2f}".format(self.average_diff)}\n' +\
            f'Positive Change:  {self.greatest_dif}\n' +\
            f'Negative Change:  {self.worst_dif}'
```